# Unable to Logout using Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new in Reactjs and usning Nextjs,I am creating on admin panel,For login
i used following code in index.js/login page ( using session if email,password correct)

```
const data = {
  name: email,
  password: password,
};
axios
  .post('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/api/testinfo3/', data)
  .then(function (response) {
    if (response.data.msg == 'wrong') {
      //display error message ( if wrong credentials entered)
    } else {
      sessionStorage.setItem('email', response.data.email); // put value into session
      const email = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
      router.push('/dashboard');
    }
  });
```

Now i want to logout,Want to destroy session and display flash message,For this i used following code in header.js (where logout button exist)

```
const handleClick = (e: any) => {
  router.push({ pathname: '/', query: { form: 'logout' } });
};

<Link href='' onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>
  Logout
</Link>;
```

And in index.js( in login page) , i am using following code

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (router.query?.form === 'logout') {
    //display logout message
  }
}, [router.query]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just navigating to home page without query param, and it's because Link is navigating not router.push

if you add e.stopPropagation(); will let router.push to navigate

like this :

```
const handleClick = (e: any) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  router.push({ pathname: '/', query: { form: 'logout' } });
};
```

and set value in href of Link component

change this :

```
<Link href='' onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>
```

to this :

```
<Link href='/' onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>
```

Comment: its working but giving me following error

"Error: The provided `href` (/blog/[slug]) value is missing query values (slug) to be interpolated properly "

Comment: aha add something in herf of Like that like '/' ,now is empty

Comment: How can we prevent someone who is not logged in but trying to open inner pages ?

Comment: Sir, its working but kindly tell me how can we prevent someone for access inner pages if not logged in

Comment: I think that's different question and would not be ok to append it to this answer , please write another question and I will answer it there

Comment: please check

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74768314/how-to-prevent-user-for-access-inner-page-if-not-loggged-in-using-reactjs

Comment: I answered that