# How to prevent user for access inner page if not loggged in Using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Reactjs and using nextjs framework,I am working on Login and logout module,I want if any user trying to access inner page without "loggged in" then he should redirect to "index/login" page,How can i do this ? Here is my current code if someone login with correct credentials

```
 const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
          sessionStorage.setItem("email", response.data.email);
          const email = sessionStorage.getItem("email");
          router.push('/dashboard');
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for checking user authentication it's better to store email or token in cookie and in getServerSideProps check cookie (because you have no access to localStorage in it)

and in getServerSideProps you can access cookie via req.cookies or use [cookies package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies)

sth like this :

```
import Cookies from 'cookies';


export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req, res, locale, ...ctx }) => {
  if (req) {
   // const posts = axios.get...
    const cookies = new Cookies(req, res);
    const token = cookies.get('email');
    if (!token) {
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: '/login',
          statusCode: 401
        }
      }
    }
    return {
      props: {
        posts,
        // your other props
       },
    };
  }
}
```

and in client code to set cookie you can use [js-cookie package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie)

forexample :

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

 const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
      const email = response.data.email
      Cookies.set('email', email )
      router.push('/dashboard');
   }
```

Comment: Sir in which file should i use this code ( getServerSideProps  ) , index.js  (login page) right ?

Comment: in any page that you don't want user see if he is not authenticated

Comment: forexample dashboard,profile, etc

Comment: On Every page ?

Comment: yes, pages that guest user cannot see

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh FYI, req.cookies is available and there is no need for external libraries.

Comment: you are right, let me up answer @Amirhossein

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh I am already using "serversideprops" or "staticprops" in some files so in that case what should i do ?

Comment: append them there and return props with other value, let me update my answer again

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh Sir, can you update your answer one more time, means please explain how to append two serverside or static props , ( just give me example )

Comment: I dont think getStaticProps would be ok for these kind of pages and I think it's better to change them to getServerSideProps .
I update the answer

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh Sir, actually in some pages i used "staticprops" so i want to know that can we us "server sideprops" in that file ?

Comment: no you cannot have both of them in same page , it's better to move codes from getStatisProps to getServerSideProps

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh How can we use multiple (2 times) serverside props in single page ? with above code ( in req, res line) i am getting erors like "req.implicity has an any type"

Comment: no not using that twice, combine them.
I added posts in my answer and axios.get to show you how to combine

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh your code giving me error sir ""req.implicity has an any type""

Comment: r u using typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this by holding a context in your whole project or a state or props in specific pages that need permission to view.

So let's assume you have a Dashboard page. You can handle your login in getServerSideProps for better experience and also redirect your user with **[redirect](https://export%20async%20function%20getServerSideProps(context)%20%7B%20%20%20const%20res%20=%20await%20fetch(%60https://.../data%60)%20%20%20const%20data%20=%20await%20res.json()%20%20%20%20if%20(!data)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20redirect:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20destination:%20%27/%27,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20permanent:%20false,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20props:%20%7B%7D,%20//%20will%20be%20passed%20to%20the%20page%20component%20as%20props%20%20%20%7D%20%7D)** property before even letting the user to see your page:

```js
export const DashboardPage = (props) => {
  console.log(props.data);
  return /* ... */;
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const res = await fetch(`Your Login URL`)
  const data = await res.json()

  if (!data) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/login',
        permanent: false,
      },
    }
  }

  /* The rest logic of your getServerSideProps */

  return {
    props: {
      data: data,
      /* other props */
    }
  }
}
```

In this way you should use the logic in every page you have.

Instead you can send the login request from client and set the response to a context value and use that context in every other pages and components.
Context File:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const UserContext = React.createContext();

export function UserProvider({ children }) {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState();
    
    const value = { userData, setUserData, isLoggedIn, setMode };

    const handleLogin = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(`Your Login URL`);
        if(res.status === 200) {
            const data = await res.json();
            setUserData(data);
            setIsLoggedIn(true);
        } else {
            setIsLoggedIn(false);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        handleLogin();
    }, []);

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
            { children }
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

And then use the values in your pages, for example Dashboard:

```js
export const DashboardPage = (props) => {
  const { isLoggedIn } = useContext(UserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(isLoggedIn === false) {
      router.push('/login');
    }
  }, [isLoggedIn]);
  return /* ... */;
};
```

Comment: Sir, First of all Thank you so much for reply,Actually i am new in Nextjs so i have 2 questions
1) what is "url" in await.fetch line ? 
2) let suppose i want to restrict user to see dashboard page but in dashboard page there is already "getserversideprops" or "staticprops" exist then what should i do ? can we use 2 "serversideprops"  in same file ?

Comment: You're welcome. I also updated my answer to use a new way to reach your purpose. About your questions: 1) url is the url that you're trying to call to login the user. 2) you can't have 2 `getServerSideProps`. Instead you should add the logic to the previous one.

Comment: please explain 2nd point, How can i use 2 different props

Comment: I edited my code and added some comments to the first section. You should write a single `getServerSideProps` and then in its return data, return your props like `return { props: { data: data, a: a, b: b, ... } }`